# How to change dates to datatime types

Tags: python

I want to change index to datatime types in order to use ARIMA model.

However I am unable to do this for daily data. Let's say I have a list:

```
dates=['24Feb','25Feb','26Feb']
```

and want to change it to datatime types, how can I do that?

I was trying with `statsmodels.tsa.base.datetools.dates_from_range` but it seems to handle only monthly or yearly data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to extract the specified components of your dates.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dates=['24Feb','25Feb','26Feb']
>>> [datetime.strptime(i, '%d%b') for i in dates]
[datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 26, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on CoryKramers answer, if you want the current year rather than 1900, something like

```
[datetime.strptime(f"{date}{datetime.now().year}", "%d%b%Y") for date in dates]
```

will dive you the current year, but if these dates have a specific year not in the string replace `datetime.now().year` with another variable.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for more information on datetimes and using strptime to get dates from strings

Comment: Thanks, this has been useful, although I had to add str() around datetime.now... beacuse one is string and the other int